# WP7 Toolkit: Open ContextMenu from ApplicationBar (contextmenu not displayed)

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, contextmenu, toolstrip, application-bar

I tried to open the ContextMenu from the applicationbar using the "ContextMenu.IsOpen()" method which will run on the event "ApplicationBarIconButton_Click". On the first button click, you see there's s.th. happening/opening. But the ContextMenu is not display correctly. It seems invisible, only the top border is displayed. On second button click everything's fine. I am using the current version of WP7 Toolkit.

XAML

```
...
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,-16,12,0">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                            <ec:GoToStateAction StateName="VisualState"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="True" x:Name="ctxContextMenu" Margin="0" CacheMode="BitmapCache" BorderThickness="2"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        ...
```

XAML of AppBar:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="False">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Click="btnExternVisit_Click" IconUri="/Images/visit.png" Text="Externe Links"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim ctxItem As New MenuItem() With {.Header = "Text"}
                AddHandler ctxItem.Tap, Sub()
                                            Dim showWeb As New WebBrowserTask()
                                            showWeb.Uri = New Uri("uri")
                                            showWeb.Show()
                                        End Sub
                ctxContextMenu.Items.Add(ctxItem)
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: ContextMenu is not displayed correctly]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the XAML for the context menu.

Comment: It's given in the code-field above, I think. I also added XAML for the appBar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a bug in Windows Phone.

After GDR2/Amber update of Windows Phone 8 everything's fine now.

I will place the button outside the menubar to get it to work for older versions.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't try to make it work for an ApplicationBarMenuItem item? That seems to not work still.

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing in your context menu. You need `MenuItem` instances inside it.

```
<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="A"/>
        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="B"/>
        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="C"/>
    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: The MenuItems and handler are generated programmatically on Sub New(). I added the vb.net code above.
The top-border of the contextmenu seems to be at the right position.